# Frame title with picture

Tags: boxes, minipage, wrapfigure

For my cv I want to create a frame box where I place my name surname and personal info on the left side and my pic on the right.

Basically I need to have a frame which width is splitted let say by 80% for text and 20% for the photo, and both share the same height.

```
----------------------------------------------
|Name and Surname                |***********|
|Bla, bla, bla.                  |***     ***|
|                                |**       **|
|                                |****   ****|
----------------------------------------------
```

How can I do such thing?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\let\\\newline}p{0.8\linewidth}%
                    |p{0.2\linewidth}|}%>{\centering}
    \hline
Name and Surname    \\
Bla, bla, bla       \\
phone: 1234567890   \\
e-mail:
    &   \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize, 
                         valign=t,margin=.5em]{example-image}    
                    \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]

or without line between columns in table:

```
    ....  
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\let\\\newline}p{0.8\linewidth}%
                     p{0.2\linewidth}|}%>{\centering}
    ....
```

[image]